# Python - I can't figure this keyError message out

Tags: python, keyerror

So, I have a game table made using `dict` and it looks like this:

```
{(0, 1): '2', (1, 2): '14', (3, 2): '8', (0, 0): '1', (3, 3): '7', (3, 0): '10', (3, 1): '9', (1, 1): '13', (2, 1): '0', (0, 2): '3', (2, 0): '11', (1, 3): '5', (2, 3): '6', (2, 2): '15', (1, 0): '12', (0, 3): '4'}
```

I made another `dict` called `A` to store those tables, using the table itself as the key:

```
A[hash(frozenset(table.tab.items()))] = table
```

Which `table` is a class:

```
class tabPlay:
def __init__(self):
    self.h = 0
    self.g = 0
    self.tab = None #I store the dict in here, that's why the table.tab
```

I also have another structure called `orderedA`:

```
orderedA[(hash(frozenset(table.tab.items())),*number*] = tabuleiro
```

used to create a ordered list of `A` using the second item from the key, so I can get the small *number* with O(1) and remove it from `A` (and `orderedA` aswell), and access the `table` I want.
The list created from `orderedA` is:

```
def getKey(item):
    return (item[0][1])
sortedA = sorted(orderedA.items(), key=getKey)
```

and this is done after every insertion on `A` and `orderedA`, so this list is always updated.

After a new `table` is created, I call this function:

```
def verify(tJ):
    key = hash(frozenset(tJ.tab.items()))
    if ((key not in A) and (key not in F)):
        A[key] = tJ
        orderedA[(key,f(tJ))] = tJ
    else:
        if (key in A):
            if (A[key].g > tJ.g):
                A[key] = tJ
                orderedA[(key,f(tJ))] = tJ
        if (key in F):
            if (F[key].g > tJ.g):
                A[key] = tJ
                orderedA[(key,f(tJ))] = tJ
                del F[key]
```

Everytime I get a `table.tab`, I compare it to the final stage I want and end the program if matches or keep going until `A` is empty.
**My problem is**: After some time running, I get a *KeyError Message* like this one:

```
    File "trabs.py", line 164, in minKey
    if (A[s[0][0]].h != heuristica):
KeyError: -3852133766700633588
```

And here is the block where the line with the error is:

```
def minKey(n):
    sortedA = deque(n)
    element = sortedA.popleft()
    print (element)
    key = element[0][0]
    for s in sortedA:
        if (A[s[0][0]].h != heuristica):
            break
        else:
            if (heuristica >= A[s[0][0]].h):
                key = s[0][0]
    return (key)

while (A):
    sortedA = sorted(orderedA.items(), key=getKey)      
    key = minKey(sortedA)
    print ('small key: ', A[key])
    element = A[key]
    del orderedA[(key,f(A[key]))]
    del A[key]
    if (element.tab == finalTab):
        return True
    if (move(element) == False):
        continue
    F[key] = elemento
return False
```

This is annoying me so badly, `A` and `orderedA` always have the same elements in it and this code already worked to one test case (not a big one), and as said before, the list `sortedA` used to get the small item is made from `orderedA`, so how it is possible to find it on the list but not in `A`?

Comment: Where in your code listed in your question is the line `print ('small key: ', A[key])`?

Comment: Note: don't surround the `if` conditions with parentheses in Python, unless you really need them. Similar for `return`: don't use parentheses (`return` is not a function call).

Comment: There's the line `A[key] = tJ` near the bottom, in the third if-clause. You check that `key in F`, but not whether `key in A`, so things could crash there.

Comment: Added the code you asked for. About the third if-clause, it is inside the else-clause and can't happen to be in A and F at the same time

Comment: What does `minkey` look like? Please make sure your code is self-contained.

Comment: Kinda big code, trying to make it easier, sorry. `Minkey` is there now, and I changed it a lil so the error message poped before, but stil the same error - the element with the specified key is missing in `A`

Comment: The advantage of creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) first when asking a question, instead of putting pieces of code from a larger code, is that the problem becomes clearer, and sometimes can be found by the author themselves. (True, it takes a bit of effort, but this question, for example, has taken 2 hours already.)

Comment: The problem was in the secod if-clause. `orderedA[(key,f(tJ))]` is wrog, the correct way is `orderedA[(key,f(A[key]))]` and should come before `A[key]` is updated.